# Define System of particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, terminology

What really is a system in physics? In laws of motion a system contains particles with same acceleration but when I studied conservation of linear momentum i found that system is just a collection of particles or bodies.

Answer (score 2):

The objects in a system don’t have to have the same acceleration. In our solar system, for example, every planet has a different acceleration.

A system of particles can be any set of particles you like, moving under any set of forces you like. It is a very general concept.

You can talk about a *closed* system, where particles cannot wander in and out of the system, or an $open$ system, where they can. Closed systems are more interesting, because they usually obey various conservation laws, such as for energy, momentum, angular momentum, and charge. If particles can wander in and out, then you have to take into account the $flux$ of the conserved quantity across the boundary of the system.

More general systems contain fields as well as, or instead of, particles. And in General Relativity you consider spacetime itself part of the dynamical system, rather than just a “place” where the system lives.

Comment: Please explain in detail about the external forces acting on the system as i am confused whether they act on each and every particle individually or as a whole system .Please answer as fast as possible as I am a beginner of classical mechanics.

Comment: Forces, whether internal or external, act on individual particles. You can sum them to get a total force which you can consider to be “acting on the system”. The internal forces (i.e. those between the particles in the system) will sum to zero but the external forces (those between the particles in the system and particles outside the system) will not. For example, think of gravity acting on a finite-sized object. Gravity is actually pulling on every atom in the object, but the overall effect is as if it were pulling on the object’s “center of mass”.

Comment: I want to ask this question again by an example:Suppose there is a system of 2 oppositely charged particles A and B which are moving due to their mutual attraction an external force F is applied on the system now this force F will be applied on the system as whole or on A and B individually if we sum this force in the system we will get a resultant force of 2F that's why I am confused.

Comment: “Applying a force F on a system” means applying forces on each particle that happen to sum to F.